# Resolve node module dependency on angular 4?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2017

I am new to angular so this maybe a trivial question however - how can I resolve a dependency on `angular` in an imported node module?

I have a component that imports `angular-md5` like so:

```
import { md5 } from 'angular-md5';
```

I have added the `angular-md5` module in `package.json`. But when I run the app I get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
```

which kind of makes sense since the `angular-md5.js` file is actually touching a variable named `angular`. As far as I've googled most suggestions involve placing a `<script>` tag in the html markup that would pull in angular, but isn't there a nicer way to do this in the angular module/component code? Is there simply an import I am missing - something like `import { Angular } from '???'`? Since I am unsure how would including an angular js file go together with the fact that angular-cli kind of generates and packs everything in the .js files. If it is of any help, here is the list of files that ng-build called from Visual Studio 2017 generates in the `wwwroot` folder:[image: List of js files generate by angular-cli]

Comment: `angular-md5` is a package for AngularJs (aka Angular 1.x);  You mention Angular-CLI briefly, and are showing Angular code (aka Angular 2/4) here. AngularJs and Angular **are not** the same framework, so a module for AngularJs can't be used in Angular without *a lot* of work.

Comment: @Claies - thanks, so as I expected I got things wrong. So I need to look for a md5 module for Angular 2/4 ?

Comment: @Claies - yep thanks, using ts-md5 from https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-md5 worked fine.